# Make a simultaneous selector and display for decibels

Tags: android, progress-bar, sound

I'm creating an android app that. I want to create a display for decibels that shows the actual noise captured by the phone. At the same time, I want the user to have an option to select the level of noise at which an alarm triggers. So, I need a display and a selector simultaneously, I don't know if separated, if together... I tried different options.

My first attempt was two concentric circular progress bars, but that didn't allow the user to 
distinguish which was which, so he had to remember. A typical decibel display (the one you see in every Android app) along with a semicicular bar on top was the second idea but they seem unpleasant together. I also attempted creating a vertical progress bar (so the user associates it with sound) in which the thumb is the number the user inputs and the secondary progress is the actual sound, but it doesn't come out as important. What would be the best option? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing this chart. Disregard the question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469434/finding-threshold-intersection-in-a-d3-chart

The chart can display the decibel values as they are happening and scrolling off-screen over time. The red line is a threshold at which to alert. You can display the numeric value of the red line along the y-axis to show the exact value.

It's also quite useful to know your audience. If they are musicians, they may have an expected visual representation of sound volume. If they are construction workers worried about hearing loss, they may not have an expectation but need it to be quickly understandable.

Most people don't know that decibels are non-linear, so it might cause confusion if you try to show a log-scale.

Comment: Audience would be any person without any kind of technical knowledge, but I think that might be good. Do you know, by change, any useful android libraries that can do that?

Comment: Regrets, no actual experience. But I've looked into https://flutterawesome.com/tag/chart/ in the past for starting points.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a switch under the read values to enable alerts and then a slider or an input to set the alert. Like this :
https://dribbble.com/shots/9474839/attachments/1500330?mode=media